# fetching is very slow in yii using CDBcriteria

Tags: yii

i have about 15000 rows in my table using cdbcrieria to fetch result , but it take too much time to load the result , can anyone please tell me the fastest way to fetch the result

i want the count of all fetched rows and method to fetch fastest result.Please help !

following is the code that i am currently using:

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
   // $Criteria->$criteria = 50;
    $currentAction = Yii::app()->controller->action->id;
    if ($currentAction == 'currentstock') {
        $storeid = isset(Yii::app()->session['storeId']) ? Yii::app()->session['storeId'] : 0;
        $criteria->condition .= ' storexparts.storeId="' . $storeid . '" AND  ( partAppStatus="1" OR partAppStatus="15" OR partAppStatus="17" OR partAppStatus="22" ) ';
    } else {
        $userId = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $storeid = isset(Yii::app()->session['storeId']) ? trim(Yii::app()->session['storeId']) : (isset($_REQUEST['storeId']) ? Yii::app()->session['storeId'] = trim($_REQUEST['storeId']) : '');
        $criteria->condition = 'storexparts.storeId="' . $storeid . '"';
        $criteria->condition .= ' AND userxfavparts.userId="' . $userId . '"';
        $criteria->condition .= ' AND userxfavparts.storeId="' . $storeid . '"';
        $criteria->condition .= ' AND (t.partAppStatus="1"';
        $criteria->condition .= ' OR t.partAppStatus="15"';
        $criteria->condition .= ' OR t.partAppStatus="17"';
        $criteria->condition .= ' OR t.partAppStatus="22")';
        // $criteria->order = 't.partCreateDate DESC';
    }
    $criteria->with = array('partUnit0', 'partCat0','fleetname', 'partType0', 'partSubCat0', 'storexparts', 'userxfavparts', 'partBrand0', 'partsalias','partPosXstore');
    if (!empty($_GET['filterProperties'])) {
        $string = implode("@", explode("\\", $_GET['filterProperties']));
        $string = implode("@", explode("'", $string));
        $code = stripslashes(trim($string));
        $criteria->addCondition("partNumber LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partsalias.aliasNumber LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partType0.typeName LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partCat0.catName LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partSubCat0.subCatName LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')
                                OR partDesc LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR storexparts.partQty LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partNotes LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partBrand0.brandCode LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partUnit0.unitShort LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')
                                OR partPosXstore.partShelf LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')
                                OR partPosXstore.partBin LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')  
                                OR fleetname.fleetcode LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')  
                                OR fleetname.fleetserialno LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')  
                                OR fleetname.fleetmodel LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')   
                                OR fleettype0.typename LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')  
                                OR fleetbrand0.brandname LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')  
                                OR engine.engineno LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')  
                                OR partsalias.aliasBarcode LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                ");
        $criteria->params = array(':filterProperties' => $code);
    }



    $criteria->together = true;

    if (isset($_REQUEST['Parts']) && !empty($_REQUEST['Parts'])) {
        if (!empty($_REQUEST['Parts']['partAliasNumber'])) {
            $partId = $_REQUEST['Parts']['partAliasNumber'];
            $criteria->addCondition("partNumber LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%') 
                                OR partsalias.aliasNumber LIKE CONCAT('%', :filterProperties , '%')");
            $criteria->params = array(':filterProperties' => $partId);
        }
    }
    $criteria->compare('partType0.typeName', $this->typeName, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partCat0.catName', $this->catName, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partSubCat0.subCatName', $this->subCatName, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partDesc', $this->partDesc, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('storexparts.partQty', $this->partQty, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partNotes', $this->partNotes, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partUnit0.unitShort', $this->unitShort, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partBrand0.brandCode', $this->partBrand, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partPosXstore.partShelf', $this->partShelf, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
    $criteria->compare('partPosXstore.partBin', $this->partBin, true, 'AND', 'LIKE');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very important**: Your select must be optimized before any other thing. If you are using MySQL, you can check [their official documentation to do it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-optimization.html).

With your select properly optimized, I suggest you to create a database view with your RDMBS to avoid overload your query with fat ActiveRecords with a lot of data and metadata. DML for build definition, in MySQL, looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW 'mydatabaseview' AS
(
   SELECT 
   ..... your select with all joins and minimal 
   ..... WHERE conditions 
)
```

Backing to the code, create a model with this database view. [You can generate model with gii code generator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii). In generated model, into `protected/models/Mydatabaseview.php` make sure to define a method `primaryKey()`:

```
class Mydatabaseview extends ActiveRecord
{
    .....

    // Define this method manually, because your database view
    // don't have primary Key

    public function primaryKey()
    {
        return 'field_from_database_view';
    }

....
```

Finally, in same model in `protected/models/Mydatabaseview.php`, use your criteria as you want:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    .......... all your conditions
}
```

If your issue continues, your probably need to use [Yii Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) instead ActiveRecord. It implies to redesign your original concept.